# AUI : Event rendering issue in month view

Tags: calendar, liferay, yui, alloy-ui, liferay-aui

Liferay's calendar portlet uses AUI scheduler. I got following issue :

I created following two an event on same day which starts on weekend(Sunday) and ends on next day (Monday)(first day of next week)

Event-A :
start-time : 12:10 PM, Sunday
end-time : 11:59 PM, Monday

Event-B :
start-time : 12:00 PM, Sunday
end-time : 11:59 PM, Monday

Ideally both the events should span across Sunday and Monday. But on scheduler (month) view it, Event-A only spans across Monday and Event-B spans on Sunday and Monday both, which is correct rendering.

Anyone have any idea on this ??

I have created a sample fiddle which will be helpful to understand this: http://jsfiddle.net/RU5xw/41/

```
YUI().use(
    'aui-scheduler',

function (Y) {
    var events = [{
        content: 'Event A',
        endDate: new Date(2013, 1, 17, 4),
        reminder: false,
        startDate: new Date(2013, 1, 16, 13)
    }, {
        content: 'Event B',
        endDate: new Date(2013, 1, 17, 4),
        reminder: false,
        startDate: new Date(2013, 1, 16, 12)
    }];

    var agendaView = new Y.SchedulerAgendaView();
    var dayView = new Y.SchedulerDayView();
    var eventRecorder = new Y.SchedulerEventRecorder();
    var monthView = new Y.SchedulerMonthView();
    var weekView = new Y.SchedulerWeekView();

    new Y.Scheduler({
        activeView: monthView,
        boundingBox: '#myScheduler',
        date: new Date(2013, 1, 4),
        eventRecorder: eventRecorder,
        items: events,
        render: true,
        views: [dayView, weekView, monthView, agendaView]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a fix available for this on Liferay marketplace. [Calendar Fix Hook](https://www.liferay.com/marketplace/-/mp/application/47162516)